# JavaScript isnt getting called before the Html

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have a script in my header that is calling a web api which should populate a view model. This is below.

```
@using GigHub.Controllers
@using GigHub.ViewModel
@model GigHub.ViewModel.ProjectsViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}

<head>
<script>
    (function getProjects() {
        $.get("/api/projects")
            .done(function () {
                alert("Got Projects");
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("Something failed!");
            });
    });

</script>
</head>
```

I then have my html that would loop through the viewModel and set it up throughout the html, but every time it gets run, it is throwing a null reference exception to Model.ProjectList in the for each because it hasn't populated yet. I thought putting the script in the header would let it run first, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
<h2>Projects</h2>

<ul class="gigs voffset4" style="width: 600px;">

    @foreach (var project in Model.ProjectList)
{
    <li>
        <div class="date">
            <div class="month">
                @project.Name
            </div>
            <div class="day">
                @project.Key
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <span class="artist">
                    @project.Id
                </span>
            <span class="genre">
                    @project.ProjectTypeKey
                </span>
        </div>
    </li>
}

</ul>
```

Here is my actual projectsController

```
 public class ProjectsController : Controller
{

    private readonly string m_Username = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
    private readonly string m_Password = Properties.Settings.Default.password;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {          
        var client = new RestClient("https://example.net/rest/api/2/");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(m_Username, m_Password);

        var request = new RestRequest("project/", Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

        var response = client.Execute<List<Project>>(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

        if (content == null)
            throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);

        var projectArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Project>>(response.Content);

        var viewModel = new ProjectsViewModel()
        {
            ProjectList = projectArray,              
            Heading = "Projects"
        };

        return View("Projects", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix javascript and C# code together and expecting it to work! No. It does not work that way.

The c# code in your view ( the `foreach` block) gets executed by razor in the server and the resulted html markup will be send to the client browser. That means, if you are accessing `Model.ProjectList` in your view, you should make sure that you are passing a model to your view with that property(`ProjectList`).

You have 2 options.

#### 1. Full server side approach

In your get action, create an object of your view model, set the `ProjectList` property and send it to view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new YourViewModel();
  vm.ProjectList= GetListOfProjectsFromSomeWhere();
  return View(vm);
}
private List<ProjectItem> GetListOfProjectsFromSomeWhere()
{
  var list=new List<ProjectItem>();
  list.Add(new ProjectItem { Name="Project 1"}); // Replace with real data here
  return list;
}
```

Assuming you have a view model called YourViewModel as below

```
public class ProjectItem
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
}
public class YourViewModel
{
   public List<ProjectItem> ProjectList {set;get;}
}
```

and 
and make sure your razor view is strongly typed to this view model

```
@model YourViewModel
<h2>Projects</h2>
@foreach (var project in Model.ProjectList)
{
  <p>@project.Name</p>
}
```

#### 2.   Use ajax to load page content.

From your client side code,make the call to your api(*like you did*) and parse the response and update the DOM.

You need to create a container element in your view so that your javascript code can append items to that from the api call result.

```
<ul id="projects"></ul>
```

Now make sure that your javscript code will execute on the document ready event.

```
function getProjects() {
    $.get("/api/projects")
        .done(function (data) {
            var projectHtml="";
            $.each(data,function(i,item){
               projectHtml+="<li>"+item.Name+"-"+item.Key+"</li>";
            });
            $("#projects").html(projectHtml);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            alert("Something failed!");
        });
}
$(function(){
    getProjects();    
});
```

Assuming your api call returns an array of item, each with a `Name` & `Key` property like this

```
[{Name:"Project1", Key:"Pr1"},{Name:"Project2", Key:"Pr2"}]
```

Comment: Ok, i guess i should have included more code. Im going with option one, and my razor view is already strongly typed to my specific view model. I will update the code with what i have. I actually had all of option one implemented at the time of the question, but it is still throwing a null argument exception in the HTML, because my GET never actually executes.

Comment: ok so the fix was changing the ApiController to just a controller so that i could return my view model into a view like Shyju mentioned. I also had to chage the GET into an INDEX so that i could call it on load.